# Texture Paint doesn't paint where I want it to

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I'm having a problem where I paint on the model, but it paints on the other side of it. I tried unwrapping my mesh with the least amount of stretch as I can, as I am new to this, but it still doesn't change.

Here's the link to the .blend file : https://drive.google.com/open?id=18csQ79BM-SYYKahkvF_Vx4N4GUuK00q4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch to Edit mode and activate the *Face Orientation* display option, you can see that your normals point inwards (the faces are red instead of blue), you need to select all and press <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate outward, then you'll be able to paint correctly.

[image]